# Duplo INSERT no stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, innodb

Atualmente oque tenho basicamente é isto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Teste`(
    IN `@valorX` INT, 
    IN `@valorY` INT
)
NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
INSERT INTO tabelaX(colunaX) VALUES (@valorX)
INSERT INTO tabelaY(colunaY) VALUES (@valorY)
```

Obs: As duas tabelas **não** tem ligação uma com a outra.

Comment: nao entendi sua duvida, voce poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Eu quero saber como fazer dois insert's ao em um procedure em duas tabelas diferentes mesmo tempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não faz sentido dois *inserts* ao mesmo tempo, já que esse comando é direcionado a uma tabela; mas podes ter dois na mesma *proc*:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE proccomdoisinserts(IN valorX INT, IN valorY INT)
   BEGIN
     INSRT INTO tabelaX(colunaX) VALUES (valorX);
     INSRT INTO tabelaX(colunaX) VALUES (valorY);
   END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```